# como guardar el resultado de los calculos del SELECT dentro de la base de datos?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

#Aqui estoy insertando 3 columnas de esta tabla hacia la tabla orden_compra
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
def copiar_tabla(self):
        selected_iid = self.cuadro_blanco_articulos.selection()[0]
        current_idx = self.cuadro_blanco_articulos.index(selected_iid)
        query=(f"INSERT INTO orden_compra(referencia, producto, precio) SELECT nro, articulo, precio FROM productos WHERE nro = {1+current_idx}")
        self.run_query(query)
```

#estoy realizando los calculos dentro del SELECT correcto? y la tabla orden_compra queda asi. tengo por defecto: cantidad.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
def consulta_orden_compra(self):
        book = self.cuadro_blanco_compra.get_children()
        for elementos in book:
            self.cuadro_blanco_compra.delete(elementos)
        query = "SELECT referencia, cantidad, producto,  precio, (precio-itbis) neto, porciento, (precio*porciento/100) itbis,  (precio * cantidad) total FROM orden_compra"
        rows = self.run_query(query)#query
        for row in rows:#Row es toda la tabla    
            self.cuadro_blanco_compra.insert('',0, text=row[1], values=row)
```

Como hago para insertar estos datos calculados con el SELECT a la base de datos?? gracias x la ayuda.

Comment: Hace la multiplicacion dentro del select y agrega la columna total a la lista de columnas.

Comment: si hago eso el resultado es ficticio y no afecta a la base de datos, solo me muestra lo que seria, si fuera calculado. necesito que guarde el calculo dentro de la base de datos.

Comment: Pero un insert afecta a la base de datos siempre y cuando hagas un cnx.commit(). No es ficticio.

Comment: no entiendo el problema...

Comment: Lo confuso del problema es que dice: *"... realizar el calculo de acuerdo a la columna `cantidad` que se encuentra dentro de `orden_compra`"*. Si se va a hacer un `INSERT`, quiere decir que el registro aún no existe, por tanto no existe `cantidad` para ese registro. Explica mejor el problema, posiblemente con la estructura de las tablas involucradas, no tienen que ser todas las columnas, solo las relevantes.

Comment: @aeportugal basicamente es, tengo 2 columnas que quiero multiplicar y que ese resultado me aparesca en la columna TOTAL y que se guarde ese resultado dentro de la base de datos.

Comment: Es que justamente no se entiende ese problema.. ya te dijeron, multiplica los valores y guardalos en la columna que quieras... cual es el problema que tuviste haciendo eso?

Comment: @gbianchi que debo realizar el calculo cuando llame a las nuevas columnas                        y no se como agregarlo dentro del insert.  ya que este toma 3 columnas y las manda a la tabla orden_compra donde se encuentra la tabla con la columna cantidad que debo multiplicar x precio y guardar esto en Total.

Comment: pero, solo agregas en el insert la otra columna que queres.. yo te pido disculpas, realmente no entiendo tu problema...

Comment: De acuerdo con @aeportugal . Suena mas a que desea hacer un `UPDATE` que un `INSERT`.

Comment: AHHHH "Como hago para insertar estos datos calculados con el SELECT a la base de datos"... si tu db, no tiene esas columnas, no, no vas a poder guardar datos creados en columnas que no existen. Si creas esas columnas, podes actualizar todos tus querys para que guarden esos datos, o podes crear un trigger que llene esa columna. Pero lo primero que tenes que hacer, es crear esas columnas.. luego, dependiendo de en que estado de desarrollo estes, son los pasos a seguir...

Comment: si intento insertar las columnas faltantes, el SQL da error diciendo: solo fueron insertados 3 valores, (los exportados), mientras que los calculos hechos por el select no los almacena en sus columnas. la cosa es que ese SELECT lo esta realizando la tabla destino orden_compra.